# Django Displaying Attribute Error

Tags: python, django

I want to send a mail to every user that fill a form on my django website. After writing a code for it, I'm getting the below error. I've been trying to find the cause of the error but no success. Below are my codes:

```
AttributeError at /meek/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'e_mail'
```

Views

```
Subject='Welcome'
message=loader.get_template('letter.txt') 
from_email='men@men.com'


def gent_me(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
       form=GentForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          data=form.cleaned_data
          newgent=Gent(
            pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
            full_name=data['full_name'],
            company_name=data['company_name'],
            services=data['services'],
            e_mail=data['e_mail'],
            address=data['address'],
            city=data['city'],
            state=data['state'],
            phone_no=data['phone_no'])
         invite=newgent.save()
         send_mail(Subject, message.render(Context()),from_email,[invite.e_mail])
         return HttpResponse('Thanks. Kindly check your mail.')
      else:
          return HttpResponse('Kindly fill form.')
   else:
       return render_to_response('ment.html',{'GentForm':GentForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include your GentForm and Gent classes

Comment: what does the Gent.save method return ? .... you might wanna replace invite.e_mail with newgent.e_mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model.save method has a return value of 'None'. So 'invite' after invite=newgent.save() is None. Instead of

```
invite=newgent.save()
```

you should do

```
newgent.save()
```

and then

```
send_mail(Subject, message.render(Context()),from_email,[newgent.e_mail])
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Must have been high on beer. Happy new year :)